# Show that a holomorphic function is bounded on all lines passing by the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Let h be the holomorphic function $h(z)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{tz}t^{-t}dt$.

I am trying to show that $g(z):=h(z-2i\pi)$ is bounded on every line passing by the origin.

I don't understand the difference between $g$ being bounded on all lines passing by the origin and the whole $\mathbb{C}$ plane ? 
Isn't $\mathbb{C}$ the union of all lines passing by the origin?

What I did:
I showed that h is bounded on $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |\Im(z)|\ge\pi\}$

I don't know how to go from there?
Many thanks!

Comment: It can be bounded on each line and still be unbounded on their union. The bound on each line could be different. The function $f(x,y)=y/x$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0,y)=1$ is bounded on each line passing through the origin, since on each of them it is a constant function. But $f(x,y)$ is not bounded on the plane, since $f(1,y)=y$  can take any value.

Comment: Great counter example, thank you!